# Array transformation for KerasR LSTM in R

Tags: python, r, keras

For using LSTM in KerasR I have to convert my NumericMatrix (335 x 1515) 
I think I found a solution here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274478/understanding-input-shape-parameter-in-lstm-with-keras 
but it is in python

```
 x_train=numpy.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))
```

and I do not know how to do it in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just assign the new shape to the `dim` attribute of the array:

```
dim(x_train) <- c(dim(x_train), 1)
```

Or use `array` to reshape and get back a new array:

```
array(x_train, c(dim(x_train), 1))
```

---

```
x_train <- array(1:10, c(2,5))
x_train
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

dim(x_train)
#[1] 2 5
dim(x_train) <- c(dim(x_train), 1)
x_train
#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

dim(x_train)
#[1] 2 5 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this was already answered, but for completition Keras in R has a built in function named `k_expand_dims()`, so you could add an extra dimension as follows:

```
x_train <- k_expand_dims(x_train, axis = 3)
```

Observation: option `axis = 3` adds an extra dimension in the "z" direction, so the array would end up being a 3D array