# R keras LSTM input shape

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

There are lots of answers on how to reshape data for Keras LSTM, but they are all about Python, not R.
[Array transformation for KerasR LSTM in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400913/array-transformation-for-kerasr-lstm-in-r)
This answer shows the transformation method, but I still have a question. What if the number of features is 2.
This is my data.

[image]

It is a temperature data. It has 290 rows and 122 cols. Each col represents a time series data for a station. And each row means the max temp for one day. I want to predict the max temp of next day using historical data, so the number of features is 122, but I do not know what is the samples and timesteps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, you should reshape data into a 3D array such that the dimensions are:  **samples: timesteps: features**

Originally I have an input matrix, *X*, with *n* columns (features) and *r* rows (observations, days).  I apply a time-lag of *m* periods on each column of the matrix, so now I have *n* separate matrices (one for each feature) with the same *r* rows, but with *m* columns, corresponding to the number of time-lags I implemented.  I squish all of these individual matrices together in the *z*-dimension, so I now have a matrix with *r* rows, *m* columns, and a depth of *n*.

I actually had my own question about this and I will be posting my own query soon on either StackOverflow or CrossValidated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very clear, but I have never seen a 3D matrice in R...How can I combine these matrices together in the z-dimension? use Array?

Comment: Correct.  It would be a 3D array.  If you have 1000 observations, each lagged 30 days, for 10 variables, your matrix will have dimensions something like `num [1:1000, 1:30, 1:10]`

Comment: If I want to use today's temperature to predict the next day's temperature, the matrix will have dimensions like num[1:1000, 1,1:10] ?  But how can I do that, it is just like a 2-D matrix...

Comment: hi, have you figured out how to reshape the input in R? I am using keras in R, and I also encountered this problem.